# Assign values to existing dictionary keys as the dictionary is being made using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

Python: Write a function named big_countries that:

- takes a dictionary (type: `dict` ) as a parameter

Input

```
country_info = {'Afghanistan': ['Asia', 652230, 25500100, 20343000, True],
'Albania': ['Europe', 28748, 2831741, 12960000, False],
'Algeria': ['Africa', 2381741, 37100000, 188681000, True],
'Andorra': ['Europe', 468, 78115, 3712000, False],
'Angola': ['Africa', 1246700, 20609294, 100990000, True]}
```

- and returns another dictionary. The returned dictionary format is:
- key → continent (type: `str` )
- value → a list of strings (type: `list` ) containing the countries (type: `str` )
  defined as ”big” in that continent or for which `country_info['country_name'][4]` is `True`

I have written the following code which works perfectly fine at doing the said task.

```
filtered_dict = dict()
for (k,v) in country_info.items():
    if v[4]: filtered_dict[v[0]] = filtered_dict.get(v[0], []) + [k]
print(filtered_dict)
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{'Asia': ['Afghanistan'], 'Africa': ['Algeria', 'Angola']}
```

But I get an itchy feeling that this can be shortened into something like:

```
filtered_dict = {v[0] : filtered_dict.get(v[0], []) + [k] for (k,v) in country_info.items() if v[4]}
```

The problem is that 1) I am dumb, 2) The `filtered_dict.get()` cannot access a dictionary before it is made or in other words we have not defined `filtered_dict` yet.

I can do something like:

```
temp_dict = dict()
filtered_dict = {v[0] : temp_dict.get(v[0], []) + [k] for (k,v) in country_info.items() if v[4]}

#Output 
{'Asia': ['Afghanistan'], 'Africa': ['Angola']}
```

But the country names get overwritten each time the same continent occurs. I want the country names to be appended not overwritten.

Can anyone help me write a shorter version of the working code possibly using recursion.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the output should be `{'Asia': ['Afghanistan'], 'Africa': ['Algeria', 'Angola']}` and not `{'Asia': ['Afghanistan'], 'Africa': ['Algeria', 'Angola'], 'Europe': []}`?

Comment: @Stef Yes, I want to only filter values with ```country_info['country_name'][4] == True```

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly simplify what you have:

```
filtered_dict = {}
for k, (x, *_, y) in country_info.items():
    if y: 
        filtered_dict.setdefault(x, []).append(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
country_info = {'Afghanistan': ['Asia', 652230, 25500100, 20343000, True],
'Albania': ['Europe', 28748, 2831741, 12960000, False],
'Algeria': ['Africa', 2381741, 37100000, 188681000, True],
'Andorra': ['Europe', 468, 78115, 3712000, False],
'Angola': ['Africa', 1246700, 20609294, 100990000, True]}

def big_countries(country_info: dict) -> dict:
    filtered_dict = {}
    for k,v in  country_info.items():
        if v[4]:
            filtered_dict.setdefault(v[0], [])
            filtered_dict[v[0]].append(k)
    return filtered_dict


print(big_countries(country_info))
```

output

```
{'Asia': ['Afghanistan'], 'Africa': ['Algeria', 'Angola']}
```